# Directing to parent directory with htaccess

Tags: angularjs, html, .htaccess

I using HTML5 urls on Angularjs for my single page application. I directed urls like localhost/project/page to index.php with htaccess code i found on the internet. If I am refreshing the page when a url like localhost/project/page/user occurs, the console seems to be in the localhost/project/page directory and my codes looks but doesn't work.

Screenshot:
[image]
(Project file is sosyalmedya)

My htaccess codes;

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And my angular codes;

```
app.config(["$routeProvider","$locationProvider",function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl:'interpages/home.php'
        }).
        when('/home', {
            templateUrl:'interpages/home.php'
        }).
        when('/notifications', {
            templateUrl:'interpages/notifications.php'
        }).
        when('/messages', {
            templateUrl:'interpages/messages.php'
        }).
        when('/search', {
            templateUrl:'interpages/search.php'
        }).
        when('/profile', {
            templateUrl:'interpages/profile.php'
        }).
        when('/profile/:user', {
            templateUrl:'interpages/profile.php'
        })
        .otherwise({rediectTo:"/home"});
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

}])
```

How can i solve this problem? I thank you in advance for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the base element in you head?

```
<base href="/sosyalmedya/">
```

try this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On  
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /sosyalmedya/index.php
```

Comment: I have a base href in index.php; <base href="http://localhost/sosyalmedya/"> . I forgot that I added this code :)

Comment: Do you have the base element?

Comment: remove localhost, put it like this <base href="/sosyalmedya/">

Comment: I added but nothing has changed. Urls like sosyalmedya/messages is working still, but urls like sosyalmedya/profile/user not working. And when i applied your htaccess code, it routing localhost mainpage beacuse of slash

Comment: The slash in front of index.html

Comment: change index.html for index.php if you use php.

Comment: I use the already changed state. This is not the reason of the error

Comment: I tried, It still going to a profile directory that does not exist.

Comment: in your routeProvider use absolute urls for your php files.

Comment: I did not understand. How absolute urls?

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
 $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl:'/sosyalmedya/interpages/home.php'
    }).
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl:'/sosyalmedya/interpages/home.php'
    }).
    when('/notifications', {
        templateUrl:'/sosyalmedya/interpages/notifications.php'
    }).
    when('/messages', {
        templateUrl:'/sosyalmedya/interpages/messages.php'
    }).
    when('/search', {
        templateUrl:'/sosyalmedya/interpages/search.php'
    }).
    when('/profile', {
        templateUrl:'/sosyalmedya/interpages/profile.php'
    }).
    when('/profile/:user', {
        templateUrl:'/sosyalmedya/interpages/profile.php'
    })
    .otherwise({rediectTo:"/home"});
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

Comment: The result is the same :(

Comment: When have two directory in the url, it going to a directory that does not exist. I think the problem is on htaccess

Comment: check the cache

Comment: I did check now.  It wasn't happen.

Comment: remove $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!'); in html5Mode you dont need it.